# How to get the list of input devices on MacOS using coreaudio?

Tags: xcode, macos, core-audio

I'm trying to get the list of audio devices in MacOS using core audio, but for whatever reason, I'm only able to get the output devices.

I'm doing a Swift UI project in XCode 13, and my code looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import CoreAudio

struct AudioDevice: Identifiable {
    let id: AudioDeviceID
    let name: String
    let inputChannels: Int
    let outputChannels: Int
}

class AudioDevicesManager {
    static func getAudioDevices() -> [AudioDevice] {
        var devices = [AudioDevice]()
        
        var propertySize: UInt32 = 0
        var status: OSStatus = noErr
        
        // Get the number of devices
        var propertyAddress = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
            mSelector: kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices,
            mScope: kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
            mElement: kAudioObjectPropertyElementMain
        )
        status = AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize(
            AudioObjectID(kAudioObjectSystemObject),
            &propertyAddress,
            0,
            nil,
            &propertySize
        )
        if status != noErr {
            print("Error: Unable to get the number of audio devices.")
            return devices
        }
        
        // Get the device IDs
        let deviceCount = Int(propertySize) / MemoryLayout<AudioDeviceID>.size
        var deviceIDs = [AudioDeviceID](repeating: 0, count: deviceCount)
        status = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(
            AudioObjectID(kAudioObjectSystemObject),
            &propertyAddress,
            0,
            nil,
            &propertySize,
            &deviceIDs
        )
        if status != noErr {
            print("Error: Unable to get the audio device IDs.")
            return devices
        }
        
        // Get device info for each device
        for deviceID in deviceIDs {
            var deviceName: String = ""
            var inputChannels: Int = 0
            var outputChannels: Int = 0
            
            // Get device name
            propertyAddress.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceNameCFString
            propertySize = UInt32(MemoryLayout<CFString>.size)
            var name: CFString? = nil
            status = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(
                deviceID,
                &propertyAddress,
                0,
                nil,
                &propertySize,
                &name
            )
            if status == noErr, let deviceNameCF = name as String? {
                deviceName = deviceNameCF
            }
            
            // Get input channels
            propertyAddress.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyStreamConfiguration
            propertyAddress.mScope = kAudioDevicePropertyScopeInput
            status = AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize(deviceID, &propertyAddress, 0, nil, &propertySize)
            if status == noErr {
                let bufferListPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>.allocate(capacity: 1)
                defer { bufferListPointer.deallocate() }
                status = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(deviceID, &propertyAddress, 0, nil, &propertySize, bufferListPointer)
                if status == noErr {
                    let bufferList = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(bufferListPointer)
                    for buffer in bufferList {
                        inputChannels += Int(buffer.mNumberChannels)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // Get output channels
            propertyAddress.mScope = kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput
            status = AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize(deviceID, &propertyAddress, 0, nil, &propertySize)
            if status == noErr {
                let bufferListPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>.allocate(capacity: 1)
                defer { bufferListPointer.deallocate() }
                status = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(deviceID, &propertyAddress, 0, nil, &propertySize, bufferListPointer)
                if status == noErr {
                    let bufferList = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(bufferListPointer)
                    for buffer in bufferList {
                        outputChannels += Int(buffer.mNumberChannels)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            devices.append(AudioDevice(id: deviceID, name: deviceName, inputChannels: inputChannels, outputChannels: outputChannels))
        }
        
        return devices
        
    }
}
```

While debugging it, it seems to ignore completely any input device. It's like they don't exist. For example, it returns the MacBook Speaker, but not the MacBook Microphone.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Are you sandboxed or using the hardened runtime? In that case you should add audio input, but I didn't think not having that would stop you listing input-only devices. Your AudioBufferList allocation looks wrong - it's not using the property size.

Comment: I tried your code in a playground and it seems to work correctly; it found `AudioDevice(id: 105, name: "MacBook Pro Microphone", inputChannels: 1, outputChannels: 0)` along with my other input devices. However, as @RhythmicFistman points out, the `AudioBufferList` allocation appears incorrect.

Comment: Thx folks. I just ran the same code in Swift playground, and it listed my input devices, so I think it should be something related to permissions in XCode. 

Neither XCode or the Swift playground appear on my Privacy > Microphone list of allowed apps. So I imagine I'll need to keep digging a bit more. 

Thx for your help!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you get a solution for this? Is it not possible to get the input devices unless the app has microphone permission?

Answer (score 0):

Within Xcode:

1. Select your project in the Project Navigator
2. Select the Target you want to add permissions to
3. Go to "Signing & Capabilities"
4. In the App Sandbox section, Hardware group, select the checkbox "Audio Input"

That worked for me.